# How to make a search in array with where collection laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, search, collections

I have data array like this :

```
[
   {
      fruit: "Apple",
      price: "10",
   },
   {
      fruit: "Orange",
      price: "12",
   },
   {
      fruit: "Manggo",
      price: "14",
   },
   {
      fruit: "Grape",
      price: "16",
   },
  {
      fruit: "Apple",
      price: "13",
   },
]
```

from my data how I make a search method to find my data with input type? Before that I wanna show what I have made, this is my code :

```
$search = "Apple"; // let's just say the value of this variable comes from the input type

$myData = [
   [fruit: "Apple", price: "10"],
   [fruit: "Orange", price: "12"],
   [fruit: "Manggo", price: "14"],
   [fruit: "Grape", price: "16"],
   [fruit: "Apple", price: "13"],
];

$getSearch = collect($myData)->where('fruit', $search)->all();

var_dump($getSearch);
```

And for output I didn't get anything from my result, like this :

```
array(0) {

}
array(0) {

}
array(0) {

}
array(0) {

}
```

And for expectation my result become like this :

```
[
   {
      fruit: "Apple",
      price: "10",
   },
   {
      fruit: "Apple",
      price: "13",
   },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$myData` is not valid php array

ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

this is fix of that

```php
$myData  = [
    [
        'fruit' => 'Apple',
        'price' => '10',
    ],
    [
        'fruit' => 'Orange',
        'price' => '12',
    ],
    [
        'fruit' => 'Manggo',
        'price' => '14',
    ],
    [
        'fruit' => 'Grape',
        'price' => '16',
    ],
    [
        'fruit' => 'Apple',
        'price' => '13',
    ]
];

$search = "Apple"; 
$getSearch = collect($myData)->where('fruit', $search)->all();
var_dump($getSearch);
```

this code result is

```json
{
    "0": {
        "fruit": "Apple",
        "price": "10"
    },
    "4": {
        "fruit": "Apple",
        "price": "13"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks before for the answer, I've tried what you told sir, but the result is still 0

Comment: @LuckALip https://laravelplayground.com/#/ test in here

Comment: sorry sir, I have a typo in my input type, my problem is already done! Thank You